# PC that is not able to browse the web for Node.js code editing and testing

Tags: pc

I have a need for a computer that I can code and test Node.js on, but is physically not capable of web browsing (an absolute requirement). It would be nice if it had internet capability (even through a gsm chip) so I can update software and test server applications.

I figured there might be some configuration where the graphics processor is not capable of powering a gui. A second thought would be a monochrome LCD with large pixels so it is not practical for web browsing.

The system should preferably be sealed and not look like a conventional laptop or tablet.

If necessary I can build it (and I know I will probably need to), it just needs to fit the requirements.

By the way, I don't care what the OS is, I just need it to run Node.js.

Edit: Just to clarify, this is for use in an environment where internet browsing devices are not allowed.

Comment: Why physically not capable of web browsing? The two examples you gave are quite simple to work around.

Comment: It needs to be impractical to web browse (for hardware reasons). Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: The only way i can think of is to let it connect to a server via peer to peer and have the server put a policy on it

Comment: It needs to be hardware disabled.

Comment: If you want it to be physically impossible, then you need to give up the network connection.  Anything capable of running Node.js is more than capable of running a text-mode browser like Lynx.

Comment: True, but the main concern is a graphical browser.

Comment: Because you don't care about what OS it runs you could could go with a linux distro that only has command line. I found a node.js build that runs on suse. If you run this on a low power embedded system with about 0.5 GB to 1 GB of ram it will be impossible to run it. I don't think there is a way for a pc to run windows and can't run a GUI browser.

Comment: I had a raspberry pi with 512 MB of ram and it ran a gui fine, though it opens up the idea for a system with <128MB.

Comment: [This thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/is-128mb-ram-enough-for-any-linux-570305/) suggests that almost any amount of ram, and almost any processor, can run a gui. I guess I will need to go down the monochrome lcd route.

Comment: are you gona use it as a developer server? if so you could just skip the GPU and connect remotely to it or let it do its thing.

Comment: I need a console.

Comment: You have contradicting requirements: "physically not capable of web browsing" and "would be nice if it had internet capability". You can only have one or the other. If you do not want connection to the outside world, you need to air gap the thing (and remove wireless communication components). If you want to update software via the internet, you have a machine that can do web browsing.

Comment: If the machine is only capable of displaying text, then I only have text based browsing, which is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Raspberry Pi. Install a console-only Debian (might need to customize post-install) and you're good to go. Supports USB, Wi-Fi, Ethernet and HDMI. Since you don't list server quality hardware as a requirement, the SoC would probably work well. Finally, it looks nothing like what most people would associate with a computer or tablet, more like a nondescript electronic device.